# Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build an android app on android studio Giraffe.
I keep having this error when I try to upgrade the kotlin version in the build.gradle

C:/Users/myself/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.4-all/56r6xik2f6skrm47et0ibifug/gradle-8.4/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

Here is my build.gradle (project)
I changed the kotlinVersion from 1.6.0 to 1.9.10 which is the one installed in Android Studio
I also changed classpath("com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android-gradle-plugin:7.+") to 8.+

All I can find on internet is "update the kotlinVersion in the build.gradle" but it seems to be the right one. And I can't find any "1.7.1" trace in the entire project.

Another problem : I changed the Android Gradle Plugin manually because the AGP Upgrade Assistant does not work, I get an everlasting loading. I detects that I am in 7.4.2

```kotlin
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
        // Only using Android Support libraries - from react-native-iap
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        kotlinVersion = '1.9.10'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android-gradle-plugin:8.+")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion" // from react-native-iap
    }
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}

subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate{
        if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my build.gradle (module)

```kotlin
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"

react {
    
}

apply plugin: "com.bugsnag.android.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle" 

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "XXX"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXX"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 270
        versionName "1"
        multiDexEnabled true // This is for method limit
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
        missingDimensionStrategy 'store', 'play' // react-native-iap
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:6.0.1"
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.1'

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")

    implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.relinker:relinker:1.4.5'

    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Comment: Check and update your dependencies. I had this problem because I didn't update one of the linked libraries that was using an old version of Kotlin. After updating this library, everything started working.

Comment: I already updated my dependencies :s

Comment: And it didn't help?

Comment: Not at all, I did it before upgrading the kotlin version
I even deleted the node_module to rebuild everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is raised because you are trying to use Kotlin 1.9.0 when the project asks for Kotlin 1.7.1.

Check your Kotlin version from Android Studio:

`Settings` -> `Languages and Frameworks` -> `Kotlin`

Check which version you are using, if you are willing to update, choose the correct version (should be 1.9.0) and install via Android Studio.

The reason AGP is not working could have multiple causes. It's a React Native project (which I'm not familiar with) but I found [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/37824)

Quote:

> **Android Gradle Plugin 8.0.x is not supported yet by React Native.** We're working on it here:
> AGP to 8.0.2 #37019
> In general, you should not bump AGP independently from the React Native version. In your case as you're on 0.71.x, the AGP version to use is 7.3.1.

To simply manage Gradle with Android Studio:

`File` -> `Project Structure` -> `Project`

And you will find your Gradle version here.

Comment: In Settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> Kotlin
My version is 223-1.9.0-release-358-blablabla and in File -> Project Structure -> Project
My Gradle Version is 8.0.1 and this is before I touch anything in my build.gradle files

Comment: Quoting from the link above: Android Gradle Plugin 8.0.x is not supported yet by React Native.