# this error occur when i try to build release project on android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-ktx

I'm building the release version of the project and I get this error. I tried changing the version of the library in the application but it doesn't work. Please help me solve this problem.

And this is the error I am getting : AndroidGooglePhotosApi/.gradle/4.6/caches/transforms-3/2d497c59f61195fb98ec1ef27205628f/transformed/firebase-analytics-ktx-21.5.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.firebase.firebase_analytics_ktx_granule.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

Hope someone can help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67448034/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version)

Comment: This fits even more https://stackoverflow.com/a/77372812/14120486