# Module was compiled with incompatible version of Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

Module was compiled with incompatible version of Kotlin. Compiled with Kotlin version is 1.9.0.But expected is 1.7.1.

Currently the app module having ktor lib version 1.6.3 and working without any issues. But upgrading ktor to the latest v2.3.9 giving this error.
Followed this migration guides
https://ktor.io/docs/migrating-2.html
https://ktor.io/docs/migrating-2-2.html

I tried updating Kotlin version in project level build.gradle and compiler version too in Android Studio settings.

Comment: Try with that https://stackoverflow.com/a/77372812/14120486