Kotlin Version Mismatch Error When Building APK in Flutter Project
I am encountering a Kotlin version mismatch error when trying to build an APK for my Flutter project. The errors indicate that some modules were compiled with Kotlin 1.8.0, but my project expects version 1.6.0. Despite multiple attempts to resolve this issue, I continue to see the following errors:
e: C:/Users/camni/.gradle/caches/transforms-4/926e2dc831cfa7efa8512a351247e464/transformed/core-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/camni/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/camni/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/camni/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/camni/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.8.22/1a8e3601703ae14bb58757ea6b2d8e8e5935a586/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

Here are the relevant parts of my configuration files:
gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-all.zip

project-level build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.24'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.4.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

app-level build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yourapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}

settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.24" apply false
}

include ":app"

pubspec.yaml:
name: meddle
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.3

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  percent_indicator: ^3.0.1
  flutter_custom_clippers: ^2.1.0
  provider: ^6.0.5
  sqflite:
  path:
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  get:
  url_launcher: ^6.1.6
  modal_bottom_sheet:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/followthemoney1/modal_bottom_sheet.git
      ref: main
      path: modal_bottom_sheet
  async: ^2.10.0
  fl_chart: ^0.36.4
  intl: ^0.17.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.20
  animations: ^2.0.7
  showcaseview: ^2.1.1
  page_transition: ^2.0.9
  profanity_filter: ^2.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  purchases_flutter: ^4.12.0
  charts_flutter: ^0.12.0
  internet_connection_checker: ^1.0.0+1
  string_similarity: ^2.0.0
  scroll_date_picker: ^3.7.3
  rate_my_app: ^2.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.13.1"
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.3

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/launch_image.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
  web:
    generate: true
    image_path: "path/to/image.png"
    background_color: "#hexcode"
    theme_color: "#hexcode"
  windows:
    generate: true
    image_path: "path/to/image.png"
    icon_size: 48 # min:48, max:256, default: 48
  macos:
    generate: true
    image_path: "path/to/image.png"

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/

  fonts:
    - family: Vaga
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/QTVagaRound-Bold.otf

    - family: Varela
      fonts:
          - asset: fonts/VarelaRound-Regular.ttf
    - family: OS
      fonts:
          - asset: fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
          - asset: fonts/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf
          - asset: fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf
          - asset: fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf
          - asset: fonts/OpenSans-Italic

I'm not sure when all of this happened, but possibly was when I moved my code from my pc to a mac so I could release on iphone. The ios portion of the project works great.
I have looked online through so many similar questions, and I know there must be a mismatch between the kotlin versions somewhere in my app but I can't find where that might be anywhere. I have been bouncing around similar error messages for 2 days now and when one goes more appear so I feel like there is a deeper issue with my code. It feels like I have tried every permutation of kotlin and gradle versions to try and get past this but no luck.
Would really appreciate a pointer in the right direction.
Many thanks.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77372812/14120486

Thanks for linking this, but I have followed the advice with no luck:
I go to file -> project structure -> project and I see "SDK: android api 34, extension level 7 platform" and "Language level: 21 - record patterns, pattern matching for switch". I then go to settings -> languages and frameworks -> kotlin and i see "starting from android studio 2023.3, kotlin will be automatically included as part of the latest release of android studio so you no longer need to update the kotlin plugin separately." I have checked and android studio is fully up to date. I cant see the incompatibility?
